# Начало разработки игр под Android

Tags: android, разработка-игр

Хотелось бы начать заниматься играми на Android. До этого читал Голощапова, там описаны только основы Андроид программирования. Сейчас хотелось бы почитать о разработке игр. Интересуют "популярные" движки, но самое главное, меня интересует хорошая документация или туториалы к ним.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Что стоит посмотреть по Андроиду.

Основы:

1. [Application Fundamentals](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/fundamentals.html)
2. [Graphics](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/graphics/index.html)

Примеры:

1. [Lunar Lander](http://developer.android.com/resources/samples/LunarLander/index.html) из SDK
2. [Snake](http://developer.android.com/resources/samples/Snake/index.html) из SDK
3. [JetBoy](http://developer.android.com/resources/samples/JetBoy/index.html) из SDK
4. [Native Plasma](http://developer.android.com/sdk/ndk/overview.html#samples) из NDK

Игровые каркасы/движки:

1. [rocon](http://code.google.com/p/rokon/)
2. [andengine](http://code.google.com/p/andengine/)
3. [angle](http://code.google.com/p/angle/)
4. [min3d](http://code.google.com/p/min3d/)
5. [forget3d](http://code.google.com/p/forget3d/)
6. [libgdx](http://code.google.com/p/libgdx/)

Для большинства простых 2D-игр достаточно классов [SurfaceView](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/SurfaceView.html) и [Canvas](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Canvas.html). А если потребуется работа с 3D, то подойдет OpenGL для встраиваемых систем (но в этом нет специфики Андроида).

Comment: 3D пока долго не потребуется.

Answer (score 3):

Еще есть [libgdx](http://code.google.com/p/libgdx/): кроссплатформенный, игры будут работать как под PC, так и под андроид. В некоторых специфичных тестах он обогнал SFML на C++ и AndEngine.

Answer (score 0):

Не люблю я эту библиотеку, но вроде Qt вышел под андроид.

Comment: Вышел, но думаю надо дать ему(Qt) время, для того, чтобы встать на ноги. И для игр он не нужен.

Comment: С последним не согласен. Каждый пишет на чем хочет.

Comment: Добавьте в свой ответ побольше аргументов в пользу Qt =)

Comment: имел дело с QT, незнаю как это будет на андроиде, ну немного не для игр он точно)

Comment: Не добавлю) Я не люблю Qt) Просто это один из вариантов.

Comment: Ну из вариантов да. Уж больно он заморочен для таких целей.

Answer (score 0):

Ну я пока-что смотрю в сторону libgdx. Незнаю чем хорош AndEngine. Хотелось бы услышать мнения.

Comment: @AndroidDev Пожалуйста, задавайте новый вопрос - в новой теме: формат форума допускает только один вопрос в теме.