# Какие фреймворки используете для создания игр под Android и используете ли их вообще?

Tags: opengles, android, разработка-игр

Добрый день! Занялся разработкой игр под Android. OpenGL ES 2 изучен. Недавно занялся вопросом, стоит ли использовать различные фреймворки (например, Libdgx) для разработки игр? Какие фреймворки посоветуете? Или от них мало толку, лучше самому писать код, используя чистый OpenGL ES?

Comment: unity, corona, cocos2d, marmelad

Comment: @aker, Постарайтесь писать более развернутые вопросы. Поясните, в чем вы видите проблему, как ее воспроизвести и т. д.

Answer (score 1):

Возможно, [это поможет](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/5053/%D0%B8%D0%B3%D1%80%D1%8B-%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%87%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%BE-%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B7%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%BA%D0%B8-%D0%B8%D0%B3%D1%80-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%B4-android).